# Build definition for branches

Tags: branch, tfsbuild

I need to create a build definition to work with the several branches of my project. I could create a definition for each branch, but I'd like to know if is there any option to create a single definition that receives a parameter informing which branch will be built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's easier to maintain if you have a seperate build for each branch, you can easily identify which build has completed by the build name (if you include the branch name in the build definition, Dev_, Main_ etc.) you could possibly do what you want but you would have to change the workspace as the first part of the build template so that you download the correct source code, doing this would stop continuous integration builds though, as these are triggered from the workspace mappings